Why can't I create a folder in a user-selected directory with FileImporter?
I am using SwiftUI's FileImporter to let users select a custom directory where I want to create a new folder. I have already done the following:
Enabled App Sandbox in the project settings.
Added User Selected File Access with both Read/Write permissions in the Signing & Capabilities tab.
Despite these steps, when I try to create a folder (e.g., "NewFolder") in the chosen directory, I get this error:
You don’t have permission to save the file “NewFolder” in the folder “Desktop”.
This error is confusing because:
The user selected the folder, so I should have permission.
Why does the error say I don’t have permission when the app has access to the path the user selected?
How can I fix this and make sure the folder is created in the user-selected directory?
import SwiftUI
    
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showFileImporter: Bool = Bool()

    private let folderName: String = "NewFolder"

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Button("Show FileImporter") {

                showFileImporter.toggle()

            }

            .fileImporter(isPresented: $showFileImporter, allowedContentTypes: [.folder], allowsMultipleSelection: false, onCompletion: { results in

                switch results {

                case .success(let fileurls):

                    guard let selectedFolder = fileurls.first else { return }

                    createFolder(selectedDirectoryURL: selectedFolder, folderName: folderName)


                case .failure(let error):

                    print(error.localizedDescription)

                }

            })

        }

    }


}



func createFolder(selectedDirectoryURL: URL, folderName: String) {


    let newFolderURL: URL = selectedDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(folderName)


    do {

        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: newFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

        print("Folder created at \(newFolderURL.path)")

    } catch {

        print("Failed to create folder: \(error.localizedDescription)")

    }

}

